# Will a PHP page get incomplete query results because said results are in the process of being replaced/recalculated elsewhere?

Tags: php, mysql

I have one PHP page which calculates the results to a poll. It starts by clearing the old results, then it iterates through several MYSQL queries to generate the new results.

I have another page which gets the results from the server for the user to view.

My question is, is there any possibility the second page will fetch incomplete results because the first page is still in the middle of generating new ones? If so, is there a workaround to avoid this conflict?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for transactions - but why not generate the results on the fly when accessing them?

Comment: Transactions sound like exactly what I should be using, thanks.

Comment: FYI my poll uses Single Transferable Vote which makes the results potentially very costly to calculate. Right now I include my calculateResults.php on my submit vote and view results page, but the script will only run if it's been more than 4 seconds and a new vote since they were last calculated.